# Create multi-stage sharepoint list with dedicated forms for each stage

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, flow

I'm attempting to create a system for people to submit ideas to the business on an intranet site which would go through a multiple stage process (Submission, Implementation, Review) and I'd like to present it to people to only enter in the information that's relevant at the respective stage of the process, either into a form or within a selective view of the list.

Is this possible?? Any info or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into modifying the form with InfoPath (you can create different views and display them depending on the value of status column) or if you prefer modern experience you would have to use PowerApp to achieve your goal. There are as well some 3rd Party providers that have this kind of functionality.